# How to compare coloumns of two different tables

Tags: sql

I have a table 1 with column 1 and column 2 and table 2 with column 1 and column 2.

I want to compare column 2 of table 1 = 'abc' and column 2 =' xyz' of table 2 
And return Column 1 of table 1 (column 1 of table 2 will be same value)

Can someone please help me

Thanks

Comment: please read [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), your question doesn't  seem clear enough

Comment: please add some sample data, DBMS used and expected outcome.  please visit this : https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

your requirement is not clear to me but it seems you need to have `join` condition or `exist` in your query

```
select column1 from table1 t1 
where exists (select 1 from table2 t2 
where t1.column2=t2.colum2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically we need to copy the data of both colums of  table in some data structures .
After iterating each element we can compare element easily.
I would prefer arraylist data structures which maintain order of element.

Answer (score 1):

You can compare both tables on behalf of the first column as you say they both are having the same value. So the following query returns you the same data tables with compare behalf of the first column.

This query return binary **[true/false]** for relative second column.

**`select tbl1.col2=tbl2.col2 as com_result from tbl1 inner join tbl2 on tbl1.col1 = tb2.col1;`**